# Get my Instagram App approved

Tags: instagram

I am trying to submit an Instagram Development App in order to get full access to Instagram API and fetch images with a specific hashtag.

My app is currently on sandbox mode and I have limited access to the API. I submitted my app to get approved and got the following answer:

"General issues: Your screencast does not show a test user logging into Instagram in your app. Please update your screencast to show the complete login experience."

What is exactly needed to do in order to get approved? Do i need to enforce instagram login to my website?

Answer (score 0):

George I believe the sandbox version of an Instagram application does give full access to all the endpoints, but places a restriction on the number of users that can use your app(10), and the content available from each user(20 images/videos).

As far as authentication, a user(including you) must be authenticated through Instagram in order to make a request through the Instagram API. For example, if I would like to use your app to look up the latest content for Roger Federer, I would need to log in with MY Instagram account in order to use YOUR application.

Instagram wants you to document this process in your application via a screencast. So essentially you would want to show them the application firing up, re-directing to Instagram for a log-in to happen, and then once authenticated re-directing back to your application for use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Stas for your reply.

My procedure is as follows:
1) Created an Instagram development account
2) Created an Instagram App to gain access to API
3) Created an access token using the app's Client Id

The call to the API is done by the app and not by each user. End users will just enter a website and see the images already fetched with i.e. a cron job request to API using my app.
We do not have user log in and we don't want to force users to log in with instagram. 

Based on that, what can I do to make my app approved?